# Workaround for quirks in contextlib.nested

Tags: python, python-2.7

I understand [why contextlib.nested is deprecated](http://docs.python.org/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.nested).

But if I write a program for an old python version w/o the multiple form of with (i. e., < 2.7), I have (nearly) no other choice.

In order to avoid the following construct to fail:

```
with nested(open("f1"), open("f2")) as (f1, f2):
```

(`f1` wouldn't be closed if opening `f2` fails, because the contextmanager is not entered)

I could imagine writing a context manager which moves initialization into its `__enter__`:

```
@contextmanager
def late_init(f, *a, **k):
    r = f(*a, **k)
    with r as c: yield c
```

Am I right thinking that

```
with nested(late_init(open, "f1"), late_init(open, "f2")) as (f1, f2):
```

will suffice here to make it "clean"?

---

The use case given is just an example. Imagine you have a list of files whose length is not prematurely known. Then neither the 2.7 composed `with` is usable nor the pre-2.7 nested way with several indented `with` statements.

---

I probably have to be more verbose about that.

The said worharound solves the prolem at first glance: calling the function is executed in a secure place so that failure can be detected and dealt with appropriately.

My question is: Does it cure the flaw, or do I get other problems?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I now saw that my solution (`late_init()`) would probably cure the first quirk:

> Firstly, as the context managers are all constructed before the
>   function is invoked, the `__new__()` and `__init__()` methods of the inner
>   context managers are not actually covered by the scope of the outer
>   context managers. That means, for example, that using `nested()` to open
>   two files is a programming error as the first file will not be closed
>   promptly if an exception is thrown when opening the second file.

But the second one:

> Secondly, if the `__enter__()` method of one of the inner context
>   managers raises an exception that is caught and suppressed by the
>   `__exit__()` method of one of the outer context managers, this construct will raise RuntimeError rather than skipping the body of the with
>   statement.

(which is probably caused by the skipped `yield vars` from `nested()`) is not covered by that.

So either

1. the use of "exception eaters" in combination with `nested()` should be avoided,
2. the given `nested()` should be replaced with a better one or
3. the use of variable length exception manager lists should be avoided and old Python versions as well.

Answer (score 2):

The *contextlib.nested* tool is for composing context managers into one.  It was deprecated because it was flawed by design (for exactly the case you've show where *f1* wouldn't be closed if opening *f2* failed).

You use case doesn't require composition though.  Regular nesting will suffice:

```
with open('f1') as f1:
    with open('f2') as f2:
        ...
```

Comment: Yes, I said that already. But this answer doesn't really answer my question. Imagine that I have not 2 files, but 5 or 10. Or I have a list/tuple of files of variable length. In this case, your solution is not really feasible.